# Chrome won't snap correctly

Tags: cinnamon, window-management

Since I upgraded to Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.1, I cannot snap my Chrome Window to the left or the right.  It only snaps to the top or the bottom, for both my laptop monitor and also my second monitor.  Every other program I tried works fine in every direction.  It's very annoying since I like to have both a browser and code editor open side by side.   I don't want to have to resize it every time.  Any one got any ideas why chrome is behaving this way?

Just to be sure, I checked another laptop running Mint 19 Mate and Chrome works fine.

Comment: What version of Cinnamon are you using (`cinnamon --version`)? I can't reproduce this on my cinnamon 4.0.3.

Comment: I'm running cinnamon 4.0.9

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same exact problem. Then, killing chrome and starting it again fixed it, hahaha.
Since this question is a month old, I imagine you probably don't have this problem anymore.